# Не могу передать данные из JS в php методом ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Суть проблемы: при попытке передать данные в PHP через метод ajax что-то идет не так, и PHP выдает Notice: Undefined index: param in. Ниже предоставляю код. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

JS-код(отправка запроса и передача данных):

```
dataset = {
          name: "name",
          email: "email",
          password: "pass",
          privileges: "user"
          };
alert(JSON.stringify(dataset));
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'registration.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                dataset: "param="+JSON.stringify(dataset)

            })
```

PHP-код(прием данных):

```
<?php
if($_POST['param'])
{
 $param = json_decode($_POST['param']);
 echo json_encode($param->email);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'registration.php',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: dataset
});

<?php
if($_POST['email'])
{
  echo $_POST['email'];
}
?>
```